# Parsing command line arguments in a python script (getopt woes)

Tags: python, getopt

Can anyone spot why the following script is not printing the passed arguments?

```
import sys, getopt

def usage():
    print 'Unknown arguments'

def main(argv):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,'fdmse:d',['files=','data-source=','mode=','start','end'])

    except getopt.GetoptError:
        usage()
        sys.exit(999)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        # print opt,arg 
        if opt in('-f','--files'):
            print 'files: ', arg  #

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

When I run the script at the command line and pass the arguments `-f=dummy.csv`, `usage()` seems to be invoked instead - WHY?

BTW, I find the logic of the program flow a bit weird (I copied it from [here](http://diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/command_line_arguments.html)). Normally, I would have thought that the logic will be implemented in the try branch, and then AFTER that comes the exception handler.

Is this (as pasted in the code above) the 'Pythonic' way to write try/catch blocks?

Comment: Hint: print the value of the GetoptError.  `except getopt.GetoptError, e: print e`.  If you don't print the error message, you'll never find out what's wrong.  Later, when you're done debugging, you can comment out the `print` statement.  For now, print the exception.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and got the error message: "option -= not recognized". I fixed the way I passed the parameters. Now the script works if I pass --files=foobar.csv  however when I pass -f foobar.csv the value is printed as an empty string ???!

Comment: Although this is not totally related to the topic but using argparse will be better and more user friendly (Since you are newbie). http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: @tushatyagi: Prob should have mentioned that I am using Python 2.6. IIRC, argparse is new for 2.7. I'll check again to be sure though

Comment: The `-f` option doesn't take an argument value. Are you confused by how to present the options top getopt?  `f:` is required to make the `-f` option look for a value.  What's your real question here?  I can't follow all the comments.  Please **update** this to make some logical sense.

Comment: optparse has its pitfalls, but it's also a good module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally, I would have thought that the logic will be implemented in the try branch

"Normally"?  What does normally mean?

What is the program supposed to do?  What exceptions make sense?  What does the program do in response to the exceptions.

There's no "normally".  Any more than there's a normal assignment statement or a normal function definition.

Your program does what makes sense to achieve the required end-state.  There's no "normally".

Comment: Normally, as in C++, C# and Java. In all of those languages, the logic is within the try block, and the exception (if its thrown), is handled later. My background (as you may have guessed) is mostly C++ (and the other languages mentioned), so I have been pretty much used to handling exceptions in the style I described - if this is not the Pythonic way of doing things, its not a problem - I just wanted to know the Pythonic way of handling exceptions

Comment: Please don't keep saying "normally".  That's a *design decision* that you make, based on what the thing is supposed to do and what exceptions may happen and what it's supposed to do in response to the exceptions.  You don't throw try blocks around randomly.  And there's no "normally".  You **must** actually think and design the try blocks.  Even in C++.

Comment: Hmm, at the risk of deviating from the original question - there is only one way to write try/catch[/finally] blocks in all of the languages I mentioned - thats why I used the word 'Normally'. I have never seen a try/catch statement where the exception handler appears before the logic that could throw an exception. Just saying ...

Comment: @ekyeagle: What?   Are you confused by which statement might raise the `getopt.GetoptError`?  Is that your real question?  If so **update** your question.  And be sure to print the exception that's raised as part of that update.

Comment: I see the point you're making. The exception handler is AFTER the statement that could throw the exception. Mea culpa. All is well again

Answer (score 2):

Did you get your answers?

One way to debug python exceptions is to move (or copy temporarily for debugging) the code out of the try block.  You'll get a full trace.

And of course another way is to reduce the test case.  Here I've reduced the problems to three lines, and tried the solution hinted at by @s.lott (using 'f:' in the getopts call), and also show at the end how calling with some different test data behaves:

```
$ cat x1.py
import sys, getopt
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'fdmse:d',['files=','data-source=','mode=','start','end'])
print "opts=", opts, "args=", args

$ python x1.py -f=dummy.csv argblah
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x1.py", line 2, in <module>
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'fdmse:d',['files=','data-source=','mode=','start','end'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/getopt.py", line 91, in getopt
    opts, args = do_shorts(opts, args[0][1:], shortopts, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/getopt.py", line 191, in do_shorts
    if short_has_arg(opt, shortopts):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/getopt.py", line 207, in short_has_arg
    raise GetoptError('option -%s not recognized' % opt, opt)
getopt.GetoptError: option -= not recognized

$ sed 's/fdm/f:dm/' <x1.py >x2.py

$ diff x1.py x2.py
2c2
< opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'fdmse:d',['files=','data-source=','mode=','start','end'])
---
> opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'f:dmse:d',['files=','data-source=','mode=','start','end'])

$ python x2.py -f=dummy.csv argblah
opts= [('-f', '=dummy.csv')] args= ['argblah']

$ python x1.py -f dummy.csv argblah
opts= [('-f', '')] args= ['dummy.csv', 'argblah']
```

Answer (score 0):

Import and use argparse instead of getopt. It's much easier to use and has almost all you need for running from the command line, built into it.

An example,

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Description of what the module does when run.')
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help='Path of log file.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

As easy as that. You need to import argparse at the top of your file for this to work, of course.